# Plotting X and Y graph from excel where x is based on row number

Tags: python, pandas

I'm fairly new to python (started coding January 2019). I'm trying to set the x coordinate based on the row number of the csv file. The y value is based on the location of the column. The data has 923 data points.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = pd.read_csv(r'csv file')
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

x = ???? #row number
y = df.iloc[:, 3]

plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (1,) and (923,)

Comment: You can also do `df.iloc[:,3].plot()`.

Comment: read_csv already returns a dataframe - you don't need to additionally try to make a dataframe out of its result.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand the question correctly then the follwowing is what you need.

```
x = df.index
```

From the docs:

> #### pandas.DataFrame.index
>
> The index (row labels) of the DataFrame.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.index.html